# Wordpress Homepage Won't Scroll (Satellite 7 theme)

Tags: wordpress

We have a strange issue, our homepage won't scroll anymore. It seems to work ok on mobile devices and all other pages on the site are fine. I've deactivated all plugins and the problem still persists. I also changed the theme and noticed the problem was solved so I know its a theme/CSS issue, but I am lost trying to figure out what could cause this in css?

Comment: It could be a javascript issue... are you seeing any errors in your console? If so, add them as code snippets in your question, or you may risk it being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

It was a CSS setting that was the culprit:

```
.no-touch body.smooth_scroll {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```